# Special file descriptors

Tags: files, file-descriptors

In shell scripting, are any file descriptors other than 0, 1 and 2 special in any way?

The flock manpage has the following example code:

```
  (
    flock -n 9 || exit 1
         # ... commands executed under lock ...
  ) 9>/var/lock/mylockfile
```

Why choose 9. Why not go for 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `9` in [flock(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/flock.1.html) is just an example (the author of the man page might have chosen 42 or many other numbers). Some shell scripts get executed in some weird contexts, in which file descriptor 3 might be already used.

(Not every script is for interactive use, some might be started internally by server daemons - e.g. mail or web servers -, others might be started by some other command; some scripts are sitting in `/usr/libexec` -outside of usual [`$PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) - because they are for internal use only)

Comment: 9 is the highest number that works in all shells. Many shells (e.g. Bourne, dash) don't parse something like `10>foo` as a redirection from fd 10.